# Происхождение слова "президент"

Tags: этимология, заимствования

Интересно было бы узнать происхождение слова ***президент,*** причём не только в русском  языке, но и в языке-первоисточнике.
Также хотелось бы узнать, когда это слово пришло к нам?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**президе́нт**
Заимствовано через нем. **Präsident** из лат. *praesidens.* Наряду с этим употреблялось **пре́зус** — "председатель военного суда" (Даль), старое **презес** — "председатель" (при Петре I).
Это слово пришло  тоже через нем. **Рräsеs** (XVIII в.) или польск. **рrеzеs** из лат. *рrаеsеs*, род. п. *praesidis*.

http://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-10256.htm

В  лат. **praesidens**, от *praesidere* — председать, начальствовать.

(Источник: «Объяснение 25000 иностранных слов, вошедших в употребление в русский язык, с означением их корней». Михельсон А.Д., 1865)

Отсюда во многих иностранных словах **ПРЕ-** означает "первый, главный".

Comment: Спасибо вам, Людмила, за полный и ясный ответ!

Answer (score 4):

**президент**
Заимств. в XIX в. из франц. яз., где **président** < лат. *praesidens*, род п. *praesidentis*, действит. прич. наст. времени от *praesidēre* — «сидеть впереди», деривата от *sidēre* — «сидеть».

(См. *председатель, сидеть*.
Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка.
Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа, Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва, 2004)

Поточнее будет, чем у торопыги Фасмера и со словом *стоять* никак не связано.

Answer (score 1):

Говоря про "всего-навсего", не надо забывать о многозначности слов.

ЧИТАЕМ СЛОВАРИ:

ПРЕДСЕДАТЕЛЬ
1. Лицо, руководящее собранием, заседанием.
2. Руководитель некоторых учреждений, объединений, обществ, организаций или их отделов, органов. *Председатель колхоза.*
3. В составе официального названия главы государства, правительства или высших государственных органов. *П. Верховного Совета СССР.*

ПРЕЗИДЕНТ [от лат. *praesidens (praesidentis*)] — сидящий впереди; стоящий во главе.
 1. Председатель, избранный для руководства обществом, объединением, научным учреждением. *П. Академии наук России*.
2. Выбранный на определённый срок глава государства с республиканской формой правления.  *Президент России.*

Сравниваем центральные значения: "руководящий собранием" и "стоящий во главе".
Делаем вывод: одним председателем нам не обойтись, вряд ли уместно выражение "Председатель России". Иначе необозначенной будет республиканская форма правления.

Comment: >Сравниваем центральные значения: "руководящий собранием" и "стоящий во главе". 

Вспомнилось старинное слово *"предстоятель"*. Тот, стоит впереди.

Но в наше время это слово употребляется, пожалуй, только в отношении служителей церкви.

Answer (score -1):

Президент - от п - первый, главный, и резидент - являющийся частью страны, государства.